# Android studio intent crash

Tags: java, android-intent, crash

When I intent an activity it always crash? I know this is a simple question but I couldn't resolve it.

```
public class Mobile_Grocery_App extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mobile__grocery__app);
    }
    public void signin(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Sign_In.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".Mobile_Grocery_App"
    android:id="@+id/rl_main_activity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_background"
        android:src="@drawable/mobile_grocery"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MOBILE GROCERY"
        android:id="@+id/mobile_grocery"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="45dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Application"
        android:id="@+id/application"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mobile_grocery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/application"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/application"
        android:layout_marginBottom="128dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"

        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:id="@+id/sign_in"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/password"
        android:onClick="signin"
        />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:id="@+id/sign_up"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/password"
        android:onClick="signup"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

P.S (I tried to clean and rebuild the project but it aint work)
    (I tried to change extend ActionbarActivity to Activity but it aint work also)

Comment: just copy paste your intent code,which you using to navigate

Comment: please add the logcat report and code where you have used intent.